# Should I save my timestamp as UTC in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I need to capture orders and I need to save the timestamp on when the person placed an order. In addition, I'll need a way to keep track of when a token is set to expire based on when the user requests a password reset code. My server is located in TX, how do I accommodate users who are located throughout the US? The last thing I want to do is ask them which timezone they're in, so I wasn't sure how to handle displaying times in UTC, which would confuse ordinary folks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should isolate *display* from *storage*. Just because you store a value in a particular way doesn't mean you have to display it that way.

Second, think about what you're actually capturing: it's a timestamp. A global idea of "now". The time zone doesn't matter here - two reasonable people in different time zones would agree on which of them placed an order first, regardless of their time zones.

It therefore feels entirely reasonable to store the timestamp in UTC. Indeed, timestamps are almost always best stored in UTC. It's only when you're asking for the *user's* idea of a date/time that local time sometimes makes sense.

As for how you display the value in the user's local time - that's tricky:

- You could guess it based on their delivery address etc
- You could guess it based on their IP address (could have some interesting issues)
- You could guess it once and store it in preferences, so they *can* fix it if necessary
- You could do it in Javascript, providing the UTC value and then converting it to local time at the client

(When guessing the time zone, you can always use UTC to local conversions in Javascript to help make that guess accurate, of course.)

Comment: Understood, I think my soluition is I need to get some sort of JS going so I can grab the person's location somehow.